ubuntu 24.0.1 did not power off after shutdown -P now or halt -p command
After upgrading to 24.04.1 from 22.04 it was unable to power off after executing halt -p or shutdown -P now.
The video output will turned off
Update on 2024-09-23
The shutdown process is trying to stop the following process but was unableCausing the stopping loop
/usr/bin/systemctl stop fwupd-refresh.timer
/usr/bin/systemctl stop fwupd
/usr/bin/systemctl stop NetworkManager.service
/usr/bin/systemctl stop systemd-networkd.socket
/usr/bin/systemctl stop systemd-networkd.service
/usr/bin/systemctl stop polkit.service
Please help
Thanks

Should we assume shutdown -O now is a typo for shutdown -P now? What happened exactly? Does systemctl poweroff work? Were there any error messages? If so, please include them.

Thanks,
No, systemctl poweroff does not work. The video signal is off, but the hard disk is still spinning.
